# Windows 10 Microphone is capturing system sound

Tags: windows-10, audio, microphone

Below is the "Recording device" settings:
[image]

And there's nothing to set in the "Microphone" (first one) to set not to capture system sound

[image]
[image]

I remember the day before the microphone didn't record any system sound, but suddenly, it does, are there any settings that need to be changed?

I tested by using the windows 10 voice recorder and play some music on my computer, but when I playback, the music appears in the recording.

Comment: Did you eliminate the possibility that it's simply picking up the sound from the speakers? That would be the most obvious reason - a microphone cannot differentiate between wanted & unwanted sound.

Comment: @Tetsujin if so, it's weird because when I chat with my friend using Skype, he's able to listen to music while chatting with me but I couldn't hear any sound from his computer, but he's able to hear the music from my computer

Comment: Sue he doesn't use a headset?

Comment: @Tetsujin oh he isn't using a headset.

Comment: Turn your speakers off (or all the way down) so you can't hear the music. Do it without using Windows mixer, i.e. with their power button, volume knob, or disconnect their power etc. Can your friend still hear your music?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski No he didn't @@"

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Weirld, after rebooting the computer, he said he can't listen to my computer system sound anymore

Comment: So you muted your speakers leaving all the Windows settings intact and then you friend couldn't hear your music. In my opinion this clearly shows that it was your microphone picking up the sound from the speakers.