# My microphone is capturing system sounds

Tags: windows-10, audio, microphone

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/1256492/windows-10-microphone-is-capturing-system-sound) or [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1556057/microphone-capturing-game-desktop-audio) does not answer my question or does not have answer.

- I am using a **headphone** which has a build in mic in it.
- I am connecting my headphone to to my PC via a [Y cable(one female(3.5mm) to two male(3.5mm) )](https://www.amazon.in/RiaTech-Male-Female-3-5mm-Headphone/dp/B077V12H3Q?ref_=fsclp_pl_dp_4)
- The problem is that my microphone is picking up my desktop sounds and other people can hear it if I'm in a voice chat(happens while I use [zoom](https://zoom.us/),[google meet](https://meet.google.com/) and also Microsoft's voice recorder,[bandicam](https://www.bandicam.com/) (happens even when i deliberately disabled capture system sounds option in bandicam)).

Some specs of my pc which might be essential to diagnose the problem.

- I am using realtek audio drivers
- OS - Windows 10 64 bit enterprise
- Headphone- Sennheiser HD 400s
- Stereo mix is disabled 
  [image]

Answer (score 1):

This might work:

1. Right click the Sound icon and select "Open Sound Settings".
2. Click "Manage sound devices".
3. Scroll down to input devices and make sure "Stereo mix" is disabled.
4. If your microphone is listed as disabled enable it.

Comment: stereo mix disabled(https://i.stack.imgur.com/iI12N.png)   mic is enabled

Comment: @Thulashitharan I'm not sure what to do then. Hopefully, somebody else can answer.